# Merging Multiple files with unequal rows based on the common column to form a count matrix file

Tags: python, linux, bash, awk

I have similar problem of merging-multiple-files-based-on-the-common-column as https://superuser.com/questions/1245094/merging-multiple-files-based-on-the-common-column. I am very near to the solution but I am new to python. I need help with the tweaking of code for joining multiple files.
My IDs and columns for individual file look like:

File1.txt

```
id  SRR1071717
chr1:15039:-::chr1:15795:-  2
chr1:15948:-::chr1:16606:-  6
```

File2.txt

```
id  SRR1079830
chr1:11672:+::chr1:12009:+  10
chr1:11845:+::chr1:12009:+  7
chrY:9756574:+::chrY:9757796:+  0
```

My desired output

```
id  SRR1071717 SRR1079830
chr1:15039:-::chr1:15795:- 2 0
chr1:15948:-::chr1:16606:- 6 0
chr1:11672:+::chr1:12009:+ 0 10
chr1:11845:+::chr1:12009:+ 0 7
chrY:9756574:+::chrY:9757796:+ 0 0
```

My code: Matrix.py

```
import sys

columns = []
data = {}
ids = set()
for filename in sys.argv[1:]:
    with open(filename, 'rU') as f:
        key = next(f).strip().split()[1]
        columns.append(key)
        data[key] = {}
        for line in f:
            if line.strip():
                id, value = line.strip().split()
                try:
                    data[key][int(id)] = value
                except ValueError as exc:
                    raise ValueError(
                        "Problem in line: '{}' '{}' '{}'".format(
                            id, value, line.rstrip()))

                ids.add(int(id))

print('\t'.join(['ID'] + columns))

for id in sorted(ids):
    line = []
    for column in columns:
        line.append(data[column].get(id, '0'))
    print('\t'.join([str(id)] + line))
```

I ran a python code as shown but it's not working correctly (being new to python). Current Output (two lines only!).

`python3 matrix.py File\*.txt`

Current output

```
id SRR1071717 SRR1079830
chrY:9756574:+::chrY:9757796:+ 0 0
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to describe the process that gets you from your sample input to your expected output (this field(s) from file1 matches with that field(s) from file2, some value foo has to be in some range, etc.), don't make us read non-working code to try to figure out what it is supposed to do.

Comment: Why did you tag bash?

Comment: Are you only interested in a python solution or solutions using other Unix tools too?

Comment: bash solution is always cool. Any solution either bash or python or both is what I need

Comment: chyY is there, please scroll towards right.. some format issues i guess

Comment: is there a significance to the `+` and `-` characters in the various IDs? could an ID show up in multiple input files but with a mix of `+` and `-`? if the answer is 'yes' then also update the question (sample inputs, desired output) to show an example

Comment: yes, these represent chromosomal locus. I have to these in my IDs.

Comment: a) just some typo error, it should be on the last row

Comment: does the order of the output matter? sort in alphanumeric order? maintain the order in which they are read? something else?

Comment: If order is maintained, its better but not essential. Thanks

Comment: bash would be a bad choice of tool for a solution but if you mean Unix tools that can be called from bash such as awk or perl or ruby (or python) then those would be appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using any awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
FNR == 1 { ++numCols }
{
    if ( !($1 in ids2rows) ) {
        rows2ids[++numRows] = $1
        ids2rows[$1] = numRows
    }

    rowNr = ids2rows[$1]
    vals[rowNr,numCols] = $2
}
END {
    for ( rowNr=1; rowNr<=numRows; rowNr++ ) {
        id = rows2ids[rowNr]
        printf "%s", id
        for ( colNr=1; colNr<=numCols; colNr++ ) {
            val = ( (rowNr,colNr) in vals ? vals[rowNr,colNr] : 0 )
            printf "%s%s", OFS, val
        }
        print ""
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk File1.txt File2.txt
id SRR1071717 SRR1079830
chr1:15039:-::chr1:15795:- 2 0
chr1:15948:-::chr1:16606:- 6 0
chr1:11672:+::chr1:12009:+ 0 10
chr1:11845:+::chr1:12009:+ 0 7
chrY:9756574:+::chrY:9757796:+ 0 0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Morton. This script is fully functional. I got two well written scripts for my problem. Super happy.

Answer (score 3):

Since you've tagged a previous (and similar) question with `awk` I'm going to assume an `awk` solution is acceptable ...

---

Adding a common `ID` (`chr8:77777:-`) to both input files:

```
$ head File*.txt
==> File1.txt <==
id  SRR1071717
chr1:15039:-::chr1:15795:-  2
chr1:15948:-::chr1:16606:-  6
chr8:77777:-::chr1:16606:-  6

==> File2.txt <==
id  SRR1079830
chr1:11672:+::chr1:12009:+  10
chr1:11845:+::chr1:12009:+  7
chrY:9756574:+::chrY:9757796:+  0
chr8:77777:-::chr1:16606:-  17
```

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
BEGIN  { hdr = "id" }
FNR==1 { hdr = hdr OFS $2
         fcnt++                                     # keep track of number of files; will serve as index of 2nd dimension of array 
         next }
       { values[$1][fcnt] = $2 }                    # populate 2-dimensional array

END    { print hdr
         for (id in values) {                       # loop through id values
             printf "%s%s", id, OFS
             for (i=1; i<=fcnt; i++)                # loop through 2nd dimension of array
                 printf "%s%s", (i in values[id] ? values[id][i] : 0), (i<fcnt ? OFS : ORS)
         }
       }
' File*.txt
```

**NOTES:**

- requires `GNU awk` for support of multidimensional arrays
- `(values[id][i] ? values[id][i] : 0)` - if the array entry is populated then print it else print a default `0`
- `(i<fcnt ? OFS : ORS)` - print the output field separator (`OFS`) except for the last pass through the loop (`i==fcnt`) in which case print the output record separator (`ORS`)

This generates:

```
id SRR1071717 SRR1079830
chrY:9756574:+::chrY:9757796:+ 0 0
chr1:11845:+::chr1:12009:+ 0 7
chr8:77777:-::chr1:16606:- 6 17
chr1:11672:+::chr1:12009:+ 0 10
chr1:15948:-::chr1:16606:- 6 0
chr1:15039:-::chr1:15795:- 2 0
```

---

Adding the `idorder[]` array so we can generate output in the same order in which IDs are read ...

```
awk '
BEGIN  { hdr = "id" }
FNR==1 { hdr = hdr OFS $2
         fcnt++
         next }
       { if (! ($1 in values))
            idorder[++idcnt] = $1
         values[$1][fcnt] = $2
       }

END    { print hdr
         for (i=1; i<=idcnt; i++) {
             id = idorder[i]
             printf "%s%s", id, OFS
             for (j=1; j<=fcnt; j++)
                 printf "%s%s", (j in values[id] ? values[id][j] : 0), (j<fcnt ? OFS : ORS)
         }
       }
' File*.txt
```

This generates:

```
id SRR1071717 SRR1079830
chr1:15039:-::chr1:15795:- 2 0
chr1:15948:-::chr1:16606:- 6 0
chr8:77777:-::chr1:16606:- 6 17
chr1:11672:+::chr1:12009:+ 0 10
chr1:11845:+::chr1:12009:+ 0 7
chrY:9756574:+::chrY:9757796:+ 0 0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Much appreciated. It worked just perfect!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way with Pandas Dataframe:

```
import sys
import glob
import pandas as pd

file_pattern = sys.argv[1]
file_list = glob.glob(file_pattern)
merged_df = None

for filename in file_list:
    column = filename.split('.')[0] 
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, delim_whitespace=True, header=None, names=['id', column])
    df.set_index('id', inplace=True)
    if merged_df is None:
        merged_df = df
    else:
        merged_df = merged_df.join(df, how='outer')

merged_df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
merged_df = merged_df[~merged_df.index.str.startswith('id')]

print(merged_df.to_string(na_rep='0'))
```

Run:

```
python matrix.py "File*.txt"
```

Output:

[image]

**EDIT:**

If the file spacing is tab (\t), please use this:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep='\t', header=None, names=['id', column])
```

instead of this line:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, delim_whitespace=True, header=None, names=['id', column])
```

With tab spacing, I checked, it also works.

Comment: Its not working, I think because my delim is tab.

Comment: @ShafaqueZahra if there is \t (tab) spacing in your files, pls update pd.read_csv function parameters. I mentioned this in the post (edit part).

Comment: Yeah. Thanks Omer. Updated! Its working!

Answer (score 0):

Also check this in Python:

```
#reading the contents of File1.txt and File2.txt
with open('File1.txt', 'r') as file1, open('File2.txt', 'r') as file2:
    lines1 = file1.readlines()
    lines2 = file2.readlines()

#extract the IDs from the first line of each file
ids1 = lines1[0].split()[1:]
ids2 = lines2[0].split()[1:]

#make a dictionary to store the values for each ID
data = {}

#process the lines of File1.txt
for line in lines1[1:]:
    columns = line.split()
    data[columns[0]] = [columns[1]] + ['0'] * len(ids2)

#process the lines of File2.txt
for line in lines2[1:]:
    columns = line.split()
    id = columns[0]
    if id in data:
        data[id][1] = columns[1]
    else:
        data[id] = ['0'] * len(ids1) + [columns[1]]

#printing the header
print('id', *ids1, *ids2)

#printing the data
for id, values in data.items():
    print(id, *values)
```

output

```
id  SRR1071717 SRR1079830
chr1:15039:-::chr1:15795:- 2 0
chr1:15948:-::chr1:16606:- 6 0
chr1:11672:+::chr1:12009:+ 0 10
chr1:11845:+::chr1:12009:+ 0 7
chrY:9756574:+::chrY:9757796:+ 0 0
```